# How to split content into equal parts then write to file in PHP

Tags: php, file, split

I have been reading/testing examples since last night, *but the cows never came home.*

I have a file with (for example) approx. 1000 characters in one line and want to split it into 10 equal parts then write back to the file.

**Goal:**

```
1. Open the file in question and read its content
2. Count up to 100 characters for example, then put a line break
3. Count 100 again and another line break, and so on till it's done.
4. Write/overwrite the file with the new split content
```

**For example:**

```
I want to turn this => KNMT2zSOMs4j4vXsBlb7uCjrGxgXpr

Into this:

KNMT2zSOMs
4j4vXsBlb7
uCjrGxgXpr
```

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php
$MyString = fopen('file.txt', "r");

$MyNewString;
$n = 100; // How many you want before seperation
$MyNewString = substr($MyString,0,$n); 
$i = $n;
while ($i < strlen($MyString)) {
$MyNewString .= "\n"; // Seperator Character
$MyNewString .= substr($MyString,$i,$n);
$i = $i + $n;
}
file_put_contents($MyString, $MyNewString);

fclose($MyString);
?>
```

But that is not working quite the way I anticipated.

I realize that there are other similiar questions like mine, but they were not showing how to read a file, then write back to it.

Comment: so where is the problem here? Reading/writing the file? or splitting the string?

Comment: @navnav Writing the split content back to file. I tried this just now `file_put_contents($MyString, $MyNewString);` but it's not working.

Comment: @navnav This works `echo $MyNewString;` but this does not `file_put_contents($MyString, $MyNewString);` what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @navnav Checked it/replied, thanks again. Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold on here. You're not giving a file name/path to `file_put_contents();`, you're giving a file handle.

Try this:

```
file_put_contents("newFileWithText.txt", $MyNewString);
```

You see, when doing `$var=fopen();`, you're giving `$var` a value of a handle, which is not meant to be used with `file_put_contents();` as it doesnt ask for a handle, but a filename instead. So, it should be: `file_put_contents("myfilenamehere.txt", "the data i want in my file here...");`

Simple.

Comment: Success! Thanks for that, and the added info.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$str = "aonoeincoieacaonoeincoieacaonoeincoieacaonoeincoieacaonoeincoieacaon";

$pieces = 10;

$ch = chunk_split($str, $pieces);
$piece = explode("\n", $ch);
foreach($piece as $line) {
// write to file
}

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).  It will take a string and split it into chunks based on length, storing each chunk at a separate index in an array that it returns.  You can then iterate over the array adding a line break after each index.